# Web scraping with R - Non HTML content - Application generated by Firebase

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I´m trying to access the Corona Virus CSV file hosted on http://covid.saude.gov.br, but there is no HTML content to parse with rvest package. The page is generated by firebase application. Here is the source code of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Coronavírus Brasil</title>

    <base href="/"/>

    <meta name="viewport"
          content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
          crossorigin=""/>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/imgs/Favicon.png"/>

    <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

      <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

      <script>
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDoHC6J1pxoKZtLNqNX4UpVWEaGdjy5ATE",
            authDomain: "covid-saude.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://covid-saude.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "covid-saude",
            storageBucket: "covid-saude.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "1097006543403",
            appId: "1:1097006543403:web:a308f2e4e006a72592706e",
            measurementId: "G-VE7NTSSB9X"
            };
            // Initialize Firebase
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            firebase.analytics();
      </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.f19219a3da5ded85f5db.css"></head>

<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.6a60e601fd1c50dddd74.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.6a60e601fd1c50dddd74.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.3f81798dab399e8c607f.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.c1f142d23713235da53a.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.3e3259fea52df4adcf5b.js" defer></script><script src="main-es2015.e24b034b00be1f140463.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.e24b034b00be1f140463.js" nomodule defer></script></body>

<script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){(function(){function a(){if(void 0===b.dialogArguments)return navigator.cookieEnabled;document.cookie="__dTCookie=1";var a=-1!==document.cookie.indexOf("__dTCookie");document.cookie="__dTCookie=1; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";return a}if(window.dT_)window.console&&window.console.log("Duplicate agent injection detected, turning off redundant initConfig.");else{var b="undefined"!==typeof window?window:self;a()&&(window.dT_||(window.dT_={cfg:"app=dfe0c9b2171df634|cors=1|featureHash=A2SVfqru|reportUrl=https://bf51981tgr.bf.dynatrace.com/bf|rdnt=1|uxrgce=1|bp=2|cuc=46s458bt|srms=1,1,,,|uxrgcm=100,25,300,3;100,25,300,3|dpvc=1|lastModification=1585265376157|dtVersion=10187200323152418|tp=500,50,0,1|uxdcw=1500|featureHash=A2SVfqru|agentUri=https://js-cdn.dynatrace.com/jstag/17052aca8bb/ruxitagent_A2SVfqru_10187200323152418.js|auto=|domain=|rid=RID_|rpid=|app=dfe0c9b2171df634",
      iCE:a}))}})();}).call(this);
      (function(){(function(){function Ob(){return ta?new ta:ua?new ua("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"):d.XMLHttpRequest?new d.XMLHttpRequest:new d.ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")}function Pb(){ua=ta=void 0}function u(){var a=0;try{a=d.performance.timing.navigationStart+Math.floor(d.performance.now())}catch(b){}return 0>=a||isNaN(a)||!isFinite(a)?(new Date).getTime():a}function R(a,b){function c(){delete la[g];a.apply(this,arguments)}for(var e=[],J=2;J<arguments.length;J++)e[J-2]=arguments[J];var g;"apply"in va?g=va.apply(d,
      [c,b].concat(e)):g=va(c,b);la[g]=!0;return g}function $a(a){delete la[a];"apply"in ca?ca.call(d,a):ca(a)}function k(a){for(var b=[],c=1;c<arguments.length;c++)b[c-1]=arguments[c];a.push.apply(a,b)}function ab(a){k(da,a)}function Qb(a){for(var b=da.length;b--;)if(da[b]===a){da.splice(b,1);break}}function Rb(){return da}function Sb(a,b){return bb(a,b)}function Tb(a,b){a=new Ub([a],{type:b});return Vb(a)}function Wb(a,b){return cb?new cb(a,b):void 0}function Xb(a){"function"===typeof a&&k(db,a)}function Yb(){return db}
      function Zb(){return Da}function eb(a){return function(){for(var b=[],c=0;c<arguments.length;c++)b[c]=arguments[c];if("number"!==typeof b[0]||!la[b[0]])try{return a.apply(this,b)}catch(e){return a(b[0])}}}function $b(){ma&&(d.clearTimeout=ca,d.clearInterval=Ea,ma=!1)}function ea(a,b){return isNaN(a)||isNaN(b)?0:Math.floor(Math.random()*(b-a+1))+a}function v(a,b){return parseInt(a,b||10)}function p(a,b,c){void 0===c&&(c=0);var e=-1;b&&a&&a.indexOf&&(e=a.indexOf(b,c));return e}function fb(a){return document.getElementsByTagName(a)}
      function gb(a){var b=a.length;if("number"===typeof b)a=b;else{for(var b=0,c=2048;a[c-1];)b=c,c+=c;for(var e=7;1<c-b;)e=(c+b)/2,a[e-1]?b=e:c=e;a=a[e]?c:b}return a}function ac(a){a=encodeURIComponent(a);var b=[];if(a)for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++){var e=a.charAt(c);k(b,bc[e]||e)}return b.join("")}function S(a){if(!a)return"";var b=d.crypto||d.msCrypto;if(b){var c=new Int8Array(a);b.getRandomValues(c)}else for(c=[],b=0;b<a;b++)c.push(ea(0,32));a=[];for(b=0;b<c.length;b++){var e=Math.abs(c[b]%32);a.push(String.fromCharCode(e+
      (9>=e?48:55)))}return a.join("")}function hb(){return!(!d.console||!d.console.log)}function cc(){try{dc.apply(d.parent,arguments)}catch(a){}}function ec(){try{fc.apply(d.top,arguments)}catch(a){}}function gc(a){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);try{hc.apply(a,b)}catch(c){}}function ic(a){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);try{jc.apply(a,b)}catch(c){}}function K(){return d.dT_}function kc(){return B}function lc(){return ib}function mc(){return jb}function nc(){return wa}function kb(){return"dtAdk"}
      function oc(){return fa}function lb(a){-1<d.dT_.io(a,"^")&&(a=a.split("^^").join("^"),a=a.split("^dq").join('"'),a=a.split("^rb").join(">"),a=a.split("^lb").join("<"),a=a.split("^p").join("|"),a=a.split("^e").join("="),a=a.split("^s").join(";"),a=a.split("^c").join(","),a=a.split("^bs").join("\\"));return a}function pc(){return T}function qc(a){T=a}function mb(a){var b=d.dT_,c=b.scv("rid"),b=b.scv("rpid");c&&(a.rid=c);b&&(a.rpid=b)}function nb(a){if(a.xb){a=lb(a.xb);try{T=new RegExp(a)}catch(b){}}}
      function ob(a){var b={};a=a.split("|");for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++){var e=a[c].split("=");2===e.length&&(b[e[0]]=decodeURIComponent(e[1].replace(/\+/g," ")))}return b}function Fa(){var a=n("csu");return(a.indexOf("dbg")===a.length-3?a.substr(0,a.length-3):a)+"_"+n("app")+"_Store"}function xa(a,b,c){b=b||{};a=a.split("|");for(var e=0;e<a.length;e++){var d=a[e],g=p(a[e],"=");-1===g?b[d]="1":(d=a[e].substring(0,g),b[d]=a[e].substring(g+1,a[e].length))}!c&&(c=b,a=c.spc)&&(e=document.createElement("textarea"),
      e.innerHTML=a,c.spc=e.value);return b}function U(a){return a in f?f[a]:ya[a]}function l(a){a=U(a);return"false"===a||"0"===a?!1:!!a}function L(a){var b=v(U(a));isNaN(b)&&(b=ya[a]);return b}function n(a){return String(U(a)||"")}function rc(a,b){f[a]=b}function pb(a){return f=a}function qb(a){var b=location.hostname;return b&&a?b===a||-1!==b.indexOf("."+a,b.length-("."+a).length):!0}function Ga(a){f[a]=0>p(f[a],"#"+a.toUpperCase())?f[a]:""}function Ha(a){var b=a.agentUri;b&&-1<p(b,"_")&&(b=/([a-zA-Z]*)[0-9]{0,4}_([a-zA-Z_0-9]*)_[0-9]+/g.exec(b))&&
      b.length&&2<b.length&&(a.csu=b[1],a.featureHash=b[2])}function Ia(a,b){qb(f.domain||"")||(f.domainOverride=location.hostname+","+f.domain,delete f.domain);f.pVO&&(a.pVO=f.pVO);b||(a.bp=a.bp||ya.bp,1===h&&a.bp1&&(a.bp=1),a.bp2&&(a.bp=2),4!==a.bp||d.JSON||(a.bp=1))}function sc(){return f}function C(a,b){try{var c=na;c&&c.setItem(a,b)}catch(e){}}function oa(a){try{var b=na;if(b)return b.getItem(a)}catch(c){}return null}function M(a){try{var b=na;b&&b.removeItem(a)}catch(c){}}function za(a,b){if(V()&&
      (!K().A||rb))return a.apply(this,b||[])}function V(){return!l("coo")||l("cooO")||rb}function m(a){document.cookie=a+'="";path=/'+(n("domain")?";domain="+n("domain"):"")+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;"}function sb(a,b,c){var e=1,d=0;do document.cookie=a+'=""'+(b?";domain="+b:"")+";path="+c.substr(0,e)+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;",e=c.indexOf("/",e),d++;while(-1!==e&&5>d)}function N(a){var b=document.cookie;if(!b)return"";var c=a+"=";a=p(b,c);if(0>a)return"";for(;0<=a;)if(a&&
      " "!==b.charAt(a-1)&&";"!==b.charAt(a-1))a=p(b,c,a+c.length);else return c=a+c.length,a=p(b,";",a),0<=a?b.substring(c,a):b.substr(c);return""}function tc(a,b,c,e){b||0===b?(b=(""+b).replace(/[;\n\r]/g,"_"),a=a+"="+b+";path=/"+(n("domain")?";domain="+n("domain"):""),c&&(a+=";expires="+c.toUTCString()),e&&(a+=";Secure"),document.cookie=a):m(a)}function D(a,b,c,e){za(tc,[a,b,c,e])}function pa(a){var b=/^[0-9A-Za-z_=:\$\+\/\.\-\*%\|]*$/.test(a);return a&&2<a.split("$").length?!1:b}function tb(){var a=
      N(B);a||((a=oa(B))&&pa(a)?W(a):a="");return pa(a)?a:""}function W(a){D(B,a,void 0,l("ssc"))}function qa(a){return 32===a.length||12>=a.length?a:""}function ub(a){if(!isNaN(Number(a))){var b=v(a);if(-99<=b&&99>=b)return a}return""}function vb(a){var b={sessionId:"",b:""},c=p(a,"|"),e=a;-1!==c&&(e=a.substring(0,c));c=p(e,"$");-1!==c?(b.sessionId=qa(e.substring(c+1)),b.b=ub(e.substring(0,c))):b.sessionId=qa(e);return b}function wb(a){var b={sessionId:"",b:""};a=a.split("v"===a.charAt(0)?"_":"=");if(2<
      a.length&&!(a.length%2)){var c=Number(a[1]);if(isNaN(c)||3>c)return b;for(var c={},e=2;e<a.length;e++)c[a[e]]=a[e+1],e++;c.sn?b.sessionId=qa(c.sn):b.sessionId="hybrid";c.srv&&(b.b=ub(c.srv));a=K();"1"!==c.ol||0<=p(navigator.userAgent,"RuxitSynthetic")||(C("dtDisabled","true"),a.disabled=!0,a.A=!0)}return b}function Ja(){return!l("dpvc")&&!l("pVO")}function ga(a){var b=document.cookie?document.cookie.split(a+"=").length-1:0;if(1<b){var c=n("domain")||d.location.hostname,e=d.location.hostname,J=d.location.pathname,
      g=0,f=0;w.push(a);do{var h=e.substr(g);if(h!==c||"/"!==J){sb(a,h===c?"":h,J);var k=document.cookie?document.cookie.split(a+"=").length-1:0;k<b&&(w.push(h),b=k)}g=e.indexOf(".",g)+1;f++}while(g&&10>f&&1<b);n("domain")&&1<b&&sb(a,"",J)}}function uc(){ga(fa);ga(B);ga(wa);ga("rxvt");ab(function(a,b,c,e){0<w.length&&!b&&(a.av(e,0,"dCN",function(){return w.join(",")}),a.av(e,4,"duplicateCookieNames",function(){return w.slice()}),w=[])})}function vc(){return ha}function Aa(a,b,c,e,d){var g=document.createElement("script");
      g.setAttribute("src",a);b&&g.setAttribute("defer","true");c&&(g.onload=c);e&&(g.onerror=e);d&&g.setAttribute("id",d);g.setAttribute("crossorigin","anonymous");a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentElement.insertBefore(g,a)}function Ka(a,b){return La+"/"+(b||X)+"_"+a+"_"+(L("buildNumber")||K().version)+".js"}function Ma(a,b){try{d.localStorage&&d.localStorage.setItem(a,b)}catch(c){}}function Na(a){try{if(d.localStorage)return d.localStorage.getItem(a)}catch(b){}return null}function E(a){try{d.localStorage&&
      d.localStorage.removeItem(a)}catch(b){}}function xb(a){if(a=a||tb()){var b=a.charAt(0);return"v"===b||"="===b?wb(a):vb(a)}return{sessionId:"",b:""}}function ia(a){return xb(a).b}function ja(a){return xb(a).sessionId}function yb(a,b){b=r(b);for(var c=!1,e=0;e<b.length;e++)b[e].frameId===ha&&(b[e].g=a,c=!0);c||k(b,{frameId:ha,g:a});Y(b)}function Y(a,b,c){if(a){var e=0===h;var d=[];for(var g=0;g<a.length;g++)if("-"!==a[g].g){0<g&&0<d.length&&k(d,"p");var f=x;f&&(k(d,f),k(d,"$"));k(d,a[g].frameId);k(d,
      "h");k(d,a[g].g)}e&&!d.length&&(Oa&&(O(0,!0,"a"),Pa(!1)),x=ia()||"",k(d,x),k(d,"$"),k(d,ha),k(d,"h-"));a=e?b||Qa():F();if(e||a)k(d,"v"),k(d,a),e="undefined"!==typeof c?c:t(),0<=e&&(k(d,"e"),k(d,e));d=d.join("")}else d="";d||0!==h||(Oa&&(O(0,!0,"a"),Pa(!1)),x=ia()||"",c="undefined"!==typeof c?c:t(),d=x+"$"+ha+"h-v"+(b||Qa()+(0<=c?"e"+c:"")));D(fa,d||"-",void 0,l("ssc"))}function r(a){var b=N(fa),c=[];if(b&&"-"!==b){for(var b=b.split("p"),d="",f=null,g=0;g<b.length;g++){var h=b[g],n=p(h,"h"),l=p(h,
      "v"),m=p(h,"e"),y=h.substring(p(h,"$")+1,n),n=-1!==l?h.substring(n+1,l):h.substring(n+1),d=d||-1!==l?-1!==m?h.substring(l+1,m):h.substring(l+1):"",f=f||-1!==m?h.substring(m+1):null;(h=a)||(h=v(y.split("_")[0]),l=u()%Ra,l<h&&(l+=Ra),h=h+9E5>l);h&&k(c,{frameId:y,g:"-"===n?"-":v(n)})}for(g=0;g<c.length;g++)c[g].visitId=d||"",c[g].j=null!==f?v(f):-1}return c}function Qa(){return F()||O(0,!0,"c")}function F(){var a=r(!0);return Z()<=u()?"":(ka(!1),1<=a.length?-1!==t()&&2<=L(Sa)&&a[0].j>=L(wc)?O(0,!0,"e"+
      a[0].j,!0):a[0].visitId||"":P(G)||"")}function ka(a){var b=u(),c=zb().m;a&&(c=b);Ab(b+Bb+"|"+c);Cb()}function Db(a,b,c){if(c&&(c=r(!0),(c=1<=c.length?c[0].visitId||"":P(G)||"")&&(c=/([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+)/g.exec(c))&&3===c.length&&isFinite(Number(c[2]))))return a=c[1]+"-"+(Number(c[2])+1),Eb(a,b),a;a||(a=ea(1,1E6));c=ja()||"";c||(c=(0===h?-1*ea(Fb,Gb)+"$":"")+S(32),W(c),c=ja(c)||"");a=""+a;for(var d=a.length,f=[],g=0;g<c.length;g++)f[g]=String.fromCharCode(65+Math.abs((c.charCodeAt(g)^a.charCodeAt(g%d))%
      26));f.push("-0");a=f.join("");Eb(a,b);return a}function Ta(a){var b=r(!1),c=2<=L(Sa)?0:-1;Y(b,a,c);Q(G,a);Q(aa,String(c));ka(!0)}function O(a,b,c,d){b&&(ba=!0);a=Db(u(),c,d);Ta(a);return a}function Eb(a,b){for(var c=0;c<Ua.length;c++)Ua[c](a,ba,b)}function xc(a){Ua.push(a)}function Cb(){Va&&$a(Va);Va=R(Hb,Z()-u())}function Hb(){if(Z()<=u()&&V()){var a=u(),a=Db(a,"t"+(a-Z()));Ta(a);return!0}Ba(Cb);return!1}function Ab(a){D("rxvt",a,void 0,l("ssc"));Q("rxvt",a)}function Q(a,b){Ja()?(Ma(a,b),M(a)):
      (C(a,b),E(a))}function Ib(){var a=N("rxvt");a||(a=P("rxvt")||"");return a}function Jb(){var a=F()||"";Q(G,a);a=Ib();Ab(a)}function zb(){var a={v:0,m:0},b=Ib();if(b)try{var c=b.split("|");2===c.length&&(a.v=parseInt(c[0],10),a.m=parseInt(c[1],10))}catch(e){}return a}function Z(){var a=zb();return Math.min(a.v,a.m+Kb)}function yc(a){Bb=a}function Pa(a){void 0===a&&(a=!0);Oa=a}function zc(){var a=ba;ba=!1;return a}function Ac(){Hb()||ka(!1)}function Bc(){if(0===h&&-1!==t()&&2<=L(Sa)){var a=r(!1),b=t()+
      1;Y(a,"",b);Q(aa,String(b))}}function P(a){var b=Na(a);b||(b=oa(a));return b}function t(){var a=r(!0);if(1<=a.length&&!isNaN(a[0].j))return a[0].j;a=P(aa)||"-1";a=v(a);return isNaN(a)?-1:a}function Ba(a){V()?a():(q||(q=[]),k(q,a))}function Cc(a){return za(a)}function Dc(){for(var a=0;a<q.length;a++)R(q[a],0);q=[];f.cooO=!0}function Ec(){f.cooO=!1;m(B);m(fa);m(wa);m("dtSa");m(kb());0===h&&(m("rxVisitor"),m("rxvt"));try{Ja()?(E(aa),E(G)):(M(aa),M(G));var a=na;a&&(0===h&&a.removeItem("rxVisitor"),a.removeItem(B),
      a.removeItem("rxvt"));(a=Wa)&&a.removeItem(Fa())}catch(b){}}function Fc(){return x}function Gc(){Ba(function(){ja()||W((0===h?-1*ea(Fb,Gb)+"$":"")+S(32));x=ia()||""})}function Xa(){var a=N("rxVisitor");if(!a||a.length&&a.length!==Ya)a=Na("rxVisitor")||oa("rxVisitor"),a&&a.length===Ya||(Lb=!0,a=u()+"",a+=S(Ya-a.length));var b=a;if(Ja()){var c=new Date;c.setFullYear(c.getFullYear()+2);Ma("rxVisitor",b)}else C("rxVisitor",b);D("rxVisitor",b,c,l("ssc"));return a}function Hc(){return Lb}function Ic(a){var b=
      N("rxVisitor");m("rxVisitor");M("rxVisitor");E("rxVisitor");D("rxVisitor",b);f.pVO=!0;a&&Ma(Za,"1");Jb()}function Jc(){E(Za);l("pVO")&&(f.pVO=!1,Xa());Jb()}function Kc(){var a=0;try{a=Math.floor(d.performance.now())}catch(b){}return 0>=a||isNaN(a)||!isFinite(a)?(new Date).getTime()-Mb():a}function Mb(){var a=0;try{a=Math.floor(d.performance.B)}catch(c){}if(0>=a||isNaN(a)||!isFinite(a)){var a=d.dT_,b=0;try{b=d.performance.timing.navigationStart}catch(c){}a=0>=b||isNaN(b)||!isFinite(b)?a.gAST():b}return a}
      function Lc(){var a=d.dT_;d.dT_={version:"10187200323152418",cfg:a?a.cfg:"",iCE:a?a.iCE:function(){return navigator.cookieEnabled},ica:1,disabled:!1,A:!1,gx:Ob,cx:Pb,mp:cc,mtp:ec,mi:gc,mw:ic,gAST:Zb,ww:Wb,stu:Tb,nw:u,apush:k,st:R,si:Sb,aBPSL:ab,rBPSL:Qb,gBPSL:Rb,aBPSCC:Xb,gBPSCC:Yb,buildType:0===h?"dynatrace":"appmon",gSSV:oa,sSSV:C,rSSV:M,rvl:E,pn:v,iVSC:pa,p3SC:wb,pLSC:vb,io:p,dC:m,sC:D,esc:ac,gSId:ia,gDtc:ja,gSC:tb,sSC:W,gC:N,cRN:ea,cRS:S,gEL:gb,gEBTN:fb,gSCN:kc,gPCHN:lc,gRHN:mc,gPCCN:oc,gLCN:nc,
      gMSIDCN:kb,cfgO:sc,pCfg:ob,pCSAA:xa,cFHFAU:Ha,sCD:Ia,bcv:l,ncv:L,scv:n,stcv:rc,rplC:pb,cLSCK:Fa,gFId:vc,gBAU:Ka,iS:Aa,eWE:Ba,oEIE:Cc,oEIEWA:za,eA:Dc,dA:Ec,gcSId:Fc,iNV:Hc,gVID:Xa,dPV:Ic,ePV:Jc,sVIdUP:Pa,sVTT:yc,sVID:Ta,rVID:F,gVI:Qa,gNVId:O,gARnVF:zc,cAUV:Ac,uVT:ka,aNVL:xc,gPC:r,cPC:yb,sPC:Y,clB:$b,ct:$a,aRI:mb,iXB:nb,gXBR:pc,sXBR:qc,de:lb,cCL:hb,gEC:t,iEC:Bc,rnw:Kc,gto:Mb}}var H=window;if(!H.dT_||!H.dT_.cfg||"string"!=typeof H.dT_.cfg||H.dT_.initialized)H.console&&H.console.log("Initconfig not found or agent already initialized! This is an injection issue.");
      else if(!(navigator.userAgent&&0<=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("RuxitSynthetic"))){var d="undefined"!==typeof window?window:self,ta,ua,da,db=[],Da,Wa,na,la={},bc=new (function(){return function(){this["!"]="%21";this["~"]="%7E";this["*"]="%2A";this["("]="%28";this[")"]="%29";this["'"]="%27";this.$="%24";this[";"]="%3B";this[","]="%2C"}}()),va,bb,hc=d.postMessage,cb=d.Worker,Ub=d.Blob,Vb=d.URL&&d.URL.createObjectURL,jc=d.Worker&&d.Worker.prototype.postMessage,dc=d.parent.postMessage,fc=d.top.postMessage,
      ca,Ea,ma=!1,h,ya,fa="dtPC",B="dtCookie",ib="x-dtpc",jb="x-dtreferer",wa="dtLatC",T,f={},rb=!!navigator.userAgent&&0<=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("RuxitSynthetic"),w=[],ha,Ra=6E8,Nb,La,X,Mc={childList:!0,subtree:!0,attributes:!0,attributeOldValue:!0},Nc=["_DT_RENDERING_"],wc="mel",Sa="vs",aa="rxec",G="rxvisitid",Va,Bb=18E5,Kb=216E5,ba=!1,Ua=[],Oa=!1,q=[],Fb=2,Gb=21,x,Za="dt-pVO",Ya=45,Lb=!1;if(!function(a){try{h=a;var b=d.dT_;ta=d.XMLHttpRequest;ua=d.ActiveXObject;va=d.setTimeout;bb=d.setInterval;
      ma||(ca=d.clearTimeout,Ea=d.clearInterval);if(!((b.iCE?b.iCE():navigator.cookieEnabled)&&("complete"!==document.readyState||d.performance&&d.performance.timing)))return!1;Lc();try{Wa=d.localStorage,na=d.sessionStorage}catch(Ca){}Da=u();da=[];la={};ma||(d.clearTimeout=eb(ca),d.clearInterval=eb(Ea),ma=!0);ha=Da%Ra+"_"+v(ea(0,1E3)+"");ya={ade:"",aew:!0,agentLocation:"",agentname:"",agentUri:"",uana:"data-dtname,data-dtName",app:"",async:!1,auto:!1,bandwidth:"300",bp1:!1,bp2:!1,bp:0===h?1:2,bs:!1,buildNumber:0,
      coo:!1,cooO:!1,cors:!1,csu:"",cuc:"",cux:!1,dataDtConfig:"",debugName:"",dASXH:0!==h,disableCookieManager:!1,disableLogging:!1,dmo:!1,dpvc:!1,disableXhrFailures:!1,domain:"",domainOverride:"",doNotDetect:"",ds:!0,dsndb:!1,dsss:!1,eni:!1,euf:!1,evl:"",extblacklist:"",exteventsoff:!1,fa:!1,fau:!0,featureHash:"",ffi:!1,hvt:216E5,lastModification:0,imm:!1,initializedModules:"",ign:"",instr:"",iub:"",lab:!1,legacy:!1,lmut:!0,lzwd:!1,lzwe:!1,mb:"",md:"",mdp:"",mdl:"",mdn:5E3,mel:200,mepp:10,moa:30,mrt:3,
      mpl:0===h?1024:100,mmds:2E4,msl:3E4,mhl:4E3,name:"",ncw:!1,ntd:!1,oat:180,ote:!1,perfbv:1,prfSmpl:0,pt:!0,pui:!1,pVO:!1,raxeh:!0,rdnt:0,reportUrl:"dynaTraceMonitor",restoreTimeline:!1,rid:"",ridPath:"",rpid:"",rt:0===h?1E4:0,rtl:0===h?0:100,rtp:0===h?2:1,rtt:1E3,rtu:200,rx_visitID:"",sl:100,sosi:!1,spc:"",srbbv:1,srbw:!0,srad:!0,srmr:100,srms:"1,1,,,",srsr:1E5,srtbv:3,srtd:1,srtr:500,srvr:"",srwo:!1,ssc:!1,st:3E3,svNB:!1,syntheticConfig:!1,tal:0,tp:"500,50,3",tt:100,tvc:3E3,uam:!1,useNewCookies:!1,
      uxdce:!1,uxdcw:1500,uxrgce:!0,uxrgcm:"100,25,300,3;100,25,300,3",vcfi:0===h,vcit:1E3,vct:50,vcv:1,vcx:50,vs:1,WST:!1,xb:"",xmut:!0,xt:0};a:{var c=K().cfg;f={reportUrl:"dynaTraceMonitor",initializedModules:"",csu:"dtagent",dataDtConfig:"string"===typeof c?c:""};K().cfg=f;0===h&&(f.csu="ruxitagentjs");var e=f.dataDtConfig;e&&-1===p(e,"#CONFIGSTRING")&&(xa(e,f),Ga("domain"),Ga("auto"),Ga("app"),Ha(f));var k=fb("script"),g=gb(k),m=-1===p(f.dataDtConfig||"","#CONFIGSTRING")?f:null;if(0<g)for(a=0;a<g;a++)b:{var b=
      void 0,r=k[a],c=m;if(r.attributes){var x=f.csu+"_bootstrap.js",e=/.*\/jstag\/.*\/.*\/(.*)_bs(_dbg)?.js$/,D=c,y=r.src,w=y&&y.indexOf(x),E=r.attributes.getNamedItem("data-dtconfig");if(E){var t=y,G=E.value,z={};f.legacy=!0;if(t){var q=/([a-zA-Z]*)[0-9]{0,4}_([a-zA-Z_0-9]*)_([0-9]+)/g.exec(t);q&&q.length&&(z.csu=q[1],z.featureHash=q[2],0===h&&(z.agentLocation=t.substr(0,p(t,q[1])-1),z.buildNumber=q[3]))}G&&xa(G,z,!0);qb(z.domain)||(z.domainOverride=location.hostname+","+z.domain,delete z.domain);b=z;
      if(!c)D=b;else if(!b.syntheticConfig){m=b;break b}}b||(b=f);if(w&&0<=w){var H=w+x.length+5;b.app=y.length>H?y.substr(H):"Default%20Application"}else if(y){var M=e.exec(y);M&&(b.app=M[1])}m=D}else m=c}if(m)for(var O in m)m.hasOwnProperty(O)&&(k=O,f[k]=m[k]);if(f.rx_visitID){var Q=f.rx_visitID;Q&&(K().rx_visitID=Q)}var aa=Fa();try{var S=(m=Wa)&&m.getItem(aa);if(S){var ra=ob(S),A=xa(ra.config||""),C=f.lastModification||"0",W=v((A.lastModification||ra.lastModification||"0").substr(0,13)),ga="string"===
      typeof C?v(C.substr(0,13)):C;if(!C||W>=ga)if(A.agentname=ra.name,A.agentUri?Ha(A):(A.csu=ra.name,A.featureHash=ra.featureHash),Ia(A,!0),nb(A),mb(A),W>(f.lastModification||0)){var ia=l("auto"),ja=l("legacy");f=pb(A);f.auto=ia;f.legacy=ja}}}catch(Ca){}Ia(f);try{var Y=f.ign;if(Y&&(new RegExp(Y)).test(d.location.href)){document.dT_=d.dT_=void 0;var sa=!1;break a}}catch(Ca){}f.useNewCookies&&0===h&&(fa="rxpc",B="rxsession",wa="rxlatency",ib="x-rxpc",jb="x-rxreferer");sa=!0}if(!sa)return!1;uc();try{Nb=
      K().disabled||!!oa("dtDisabled")}catch(Ca){}var F;if(!(F=n("agentLocation")))a:{var Z=n("agentUri");if(Z||document.currentScript){var I=Z||document.currentScript.src;if(I){var ka=-1===p(I,"_bs")&&-1===p(I,"_bootstrap")&&-1===p(I,"_complete")?1:2,P=I.lastIndexOf("/");for(sa=0;sa<ka&&-1!==P;sa++)I=I.substr(0,P),P=I.lastIndexOf("/");F=I;break a}}var ba=location.pathname;F=ba.substr(0,ba.lastIndexOf("/"))}La=F;X=n("agentname")||n("csu")||(0===h?"ruxitagentjs":"dtagent");"true"===N("dtUseDebugAgent")?
      0>X.indexOf("dbg")&&(X=n("debugName")||X+"dbg"):X=n("name")||X;if(!l("auto")&&!l("legacy")&&!Nb){var R=n("agentUri")||Ka(n("featureHash")),T;if(!(T=l("async")||"complete"===document.readyState)){var U=d.navigator.userAgent,V=U.indexOf("MSIE ");T=0<V?9>=parseInt(U.substring(V+5,U.indexOf(".",V)),10):!1}T?Aa(R,l("async"),void 0,void 0,"dtjsagent"):(document.write('<script id="dtjsagentdw" type="text/javascript" src="'+R+'">\x3c/script>'),document.getElementById("dtjsagentdw")||Aa(R,l("async"),void 0,
      void 0,"dtjsagent"))}var pa=d.location.href;0===h&&-1!==p(pa,"_DT_RENDERING_")&&(K().RMOD={conf:Mc,ignore:Nc,ID:"_DT_RENDERING_"},La&&Aa(Ka("R"),!0,void 0,void 0,"dtjsagent"));N(B)&&(f.cooO=!0);Gc();if(0===h){var qa=!!Na(Za);f.pVO=qa;Ba(Xa)}0===h&&L("hvt")&&(Kb=L("hvt"));za(yb,[1])}catch(Ca){return!1}return!0}(0)){try{delete d.dT_}catch(a){d.dT_=void 0}hb()&&d.console.log("JsAgent initCode initialization failed!")}}})();}).call(this);
  </script>
</html>
```

How can I access the CSV file related to the highlighted link shown ?

[corona.saude.gov.br site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyfiX.png)

Comment: The page is using some javascript to connect to the data source, Here are some over potential Covid-19 sources https://towardsdatascience.com/a-short-review-of-covid-19-data-sources-ba7f7aa1c342,  Listed are some other potential options.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the download button you can see the generated url. You can use that with `read.csv` and specify the `;` delimiter

```
f <- read.csv('https://mobileapps.saude.gov.br/esus-vepi/files/unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm/1d2b944e065c7304b2754cc386635e38_Download_COVID19_20200430.csv',sep = ';')
View(f)
```

Though if those initial identifiers vary over time then code would break. In that case using a tool like RSelenium to automate browser and click the download button might be an option.

Comment: I'am trying to scrap the same data and unfortunately the URL changes each day (the final part). Today it is `https://<same_thing/files/b7ac2be9055d75727e05608cb181cc74_Download_COVID19_20200504.csv`
Is selenium the only way to go then?

Comment: I think the hex like identifiers come from firebase and unobtainable to us. I could be wrong. Selenium, imo, would be the safer bet.

Comment: Yeah, the number seems to be unobtainable. I could make it work with selenium, but it's in Python.

Comment: I mean in the sense that it does not exactly answer the op question that specifically asked for R.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: The website was changed and thus this solution does not work anymore. However, It can be adapted to the new website and thus I'm leaving the answer for future reference.**

---

The download link is generated when the button is clicked and it is in the form

`https://mobileapps.saude.gov.br/esus-vepi/files/unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm/<a_32_digit_hexadecimal_number>_Download_COVID19_<YYYYMMDD>.csv`

The link changes each day and while the date part is easy, the 32 digit hexadecimal number also changes and we don't know how it is computed.

I tried to finding some API call using firefox dev tools that could be used to get the link (which javascript function is called to handle the click of the button), but without luck. The packing of the assets makes this very complicated, at least to my experience level, since I'm no web developer.

This leaves us with selenium probably being the only option. Here is a solution in Python, which should not be difficult to adapt to R.

```py
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

URL = "https://covid.saude.gov.br/"

# Create a profile and set some preferences to prevent download dialog
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
# The value is the folder where to download to. We are setting the download
# folder as the current folder of the python interpreter by using 'os.getcwd'
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')

# Create a driver and load the webpage -> This blocks until the page
# You need to install a driver. I'm using a driver for firefox
# See here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get(URL)

# The webpage uses shadow-dom in several places, but we can get the download
# button by get all "button"s from the page
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button")

# The download button is the third one (index 2)
download_button = buttons[2]

# When we run this script we should wait a bit before clicking the download
# button. I'm waiting 2 seconds to be safe
sleep(2.0)

# Click the button
download_button.click()


# Sleep before closing the driver to allow time for the download. If we close
# the driver to quickly the window will be closed before the download is
# finished
sleep(3.0)

# Close the driver -> This closes the firefox window that was opened by selenium
driver.close()
```

Note that you need to install a [selenium driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers) before this can be used. Also, you might need to tweek the sleep values that I have used.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                          chromever =
                            system2(command = "wmic",
                                    args = 'datafile where name="C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe" get Version /value',
                                    stdout = TRUE,
                                    stderr = TRUE) %>%
                            stringr::str_extract(pattern = "(?<=Version=)\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.") %>%
                            magrittr::extract(!is.na(.)) %>%
                            stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "\\.",
                                                     replacement = "\\\\.") %>%
                            paste0("^",  .) %>%
                            stringr::str_subset(string =
                                                  binman::list_versions(appname = "chromedriver") %>%
                                                  dplyr::last()) %>%
                            as.numeric_version() %>%
                            max() %>%
                            as.character())
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]] 
remote_driver$navigate("https://covid.saude.gov.br")
button_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'class', value = "btn-outline")
button_element$clickElement()
```

Comment: I´m trying to use this script in Spotfire within Data Function, but I think that wont work because the data function must be executed on a Spotfire web player.